# How to Insulate/Install Moisture barrier around drain pipes in basement

Tags: insulation, basement

finishing my basement and 2" using rigid insulation on the concrete walls for a moisture barrier/thermal break. My plan is to tape that all to my DriCore InsulArmor subfloor for a seam-less moisture/thermal break.

My challenge is I'm not sure how to insulate around these drain pipes. Prior to me finishing the basement, they had a large 4x8 sheets of insulation (with a thick poly side) crammed in the 1/2-1" gap behind the pipes, then it was taped to the pipes to "seal" it. My plan is to build a wall along the concrete (off the rigid insulation), then another perpendicular wall where the red marks are. The wall its on is technically next to our garage, which I would think the ground under the garage wouldnt freeze as much/deep. Iowa, new construction for reference.

I see a couple of options

1. Keep the heavy sheets of insulation behind the pipes, frame out like a hacked-together 2x10 wall for that section, and fill the remaining space with normal insulation
2. Cut out the 2" insulation to closely match the shape of the drain, then spray foam behind/to the sides of the pipes to "seal"/insulate it, build a wall off of that (notching where necessary).

I read I want to keep those pipes "fairly" accessible should they need replacement/fixing. Or is there some other approach that I should be taking?

[image]